# How to center images while keeping them responsive?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, responsive-design, image-scaling

Hi please take a look at my site, below is the code snippet in question i have to center my images since ive never had any luck with the css-html methods. The problem is because its set to wait for document.ready() sometimes it will place all my images to the right. Ive tried window.load() but the images center offscreen at smaller window sizes. It was also suggested i try

```
<div style="
  background: url('Assets/image.png') center center no-repeat;
  width: 100%;
  height: 500px;
 ">
 </div>
```

but this causes it to lose responsiveness. Ive searched around and i cant find a solution, i just need my images (and the one form) to stay centered and for the images to scale down with the window size.

site: http://bit.ly/11nAQJK

```
<script type="text/javascript"> //Centering Script


$(document).ready(function () {
    updateContainer();
    $(window).resize(function() {
        updateContainer();
    });
});


function updateContainer() {


(function ($) {
$.fn.vAlign = function() {
    return this.each(function(i){
    var h = $(this).height();
    var oh = $(this).outerHeight();
    var mt = (h + (oh - h)) / 2;    
    $(this).css("margin-top", "-" + mt + "px"); 
    $(this).css("top", "50%");
    $(this).css("position", "absolute");    
    }); 
};
})(jQuery);

(function ($) {
$.fn.hAlign = function() {
    return this.each(function(i){
    var w = $(this).width();
    var ow = $(this).outerWidth();  
    var ml = (w + (ow - w)) / 2;    
    $(this).css("margin-left", "-" + ml + "px");
    $(this).css("left", "50%");
    $(this).css("position", "absolute");
    });
};
})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 3):

Remove that whole script. Place this in your CSS.

```
img{
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Comment: The images arent responsive with this method

Comment: Then add max-width and height auto to the image. The previous code is for centering the image.

Comment: Yes thats what another poster put, but how do i apply it to the form on my page?

Comment: Also what if my images have more than one width?

Comment: Alright i can see you really want to help but your solution forces to assume every image has the same width.

Answer (score 0):

just do

```
<style>
a{
display:block;
text-align:center;
}

</style>



<a href="Assets/OrderSheet.xls">
    <img src="Assets/OrderSheet.png" class="image">
</a>
```

no need for repositioning

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/delueg/Yn7ex/)

Comment: But this screws up the links on my page!

Comment: why ... what do you mean? you can give the <a> tags a class and dou it like a.img_links{display:block;
text-align:center;}... but i saw you were able to manage this on your page anyway

Answer (score 0):

No need for js, CSS alone is fine. Set your image to display block, set a width and Max width plus margin auto.

```
img {
display: block;
width: 300px;
max-width: 100%;
margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Comment: Thank you that works! But how do i apply it to the form on my page (the button)?

Comment: What do i do if my images have more than one width?

Comment: Yeah actually this solution doesnt work at all i cant just blanket apply a width to every image on my page.

Comment: you don't need to apply a blanket width to every img on your page. Just set a `max-width: 100%`. The same applies to a `form` too.

Answer (score 0):

If you won't accept the method suggested by others, I would suggest using `em's`. Best to use them everywhere, but you could just apply them to your images.

Then use `media queries` to scale up/down all elements with values specified in `em's`, by changing the base `font-size` for different screen sizes.

Answer (score 0):

center a responsive sized element

```
/* element/id/class */ 
/* margin is 100 - width / 2 */

img {
width:34%;    
margin: 0 33%;
}
```